# When you subscribe to event on kafka can I add argument to the subscription

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

my system connect to an external "microservice A".(let's say it return weather disaster forecast) 
"microservice A" do not know anything regard my system and users.
in case I have a user that have been subscribed to this service,

1. Is it possible to subscribe to a message broker with argument such "userid" so when it will return the answer I will be able to know this user have been subscribe and send him the answer.

1.1. In case the answer is yes is it the best practice since now I will have millions subscribers with userid instead of one subscription and then pull all the users that have been subscribed and send it to them the notification

What is the best choice here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no further projection of querying you can do than a partition of a topic. In other words, ID lookup is not possible when scanning a topic without actually inspecting each record.

You could, however, use a Stream Processing Engine to filter out certain user IDs into different topics for downstream processes to consume, or you can build a table of all events, grouped by userId.

> I will be able to know this user have been subscribe and send him the answer

In Kafka API, consumers are asking for the data themselves, they are not being "sent" anything